# Jetpack Compose why is onValueChange getting called over and over?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

This code works as expected.  The println only prints when the text value changes or the user moves the cursor

```
val testText = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue()) }
TextField(
    value = testText.value,
    onValueChange = {
        // should only happen when you type or move cursor
        println("onValueChange called")
        testText.value = it.copy(
            annotatedString = buildAnnotatedString {
                append(it.text)
            },
        )
    },
)
```

However, some strange things happen when I add a style span:

```
val testText = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue()) }
TextField(
    value = testText.value,
    onValueChange = {
        // should only happen when you type or move cursor
        println("onValueChange called")
        testText.value = it.copy(
            annotatedString = buildAnnotatedString {
                withStyle(SpanStyle(Color.Blue)) {
                    append(it.text)
                }
            },
        )
    },
)
```

As I type, if my cursor is located in a word that begins with a letter, then the println is continuously called.  But if my cursor is in a word that doesn't start with a letter, then the println acts normal.  For example, if my text looks like `@john{cursor here} is a person` or `john 9{cursor here}9 test` then it's normal.  But if my text looks like `john{cursor here} is a person` then I get the continuous prints.

Why is this happening?

Edit: I found out this is happening due to IME auto suggestions.  I got this to work by using the `TextField` `visualTransformation` parameters instead of applying the style directly to the `TextFieldValue`.

Answer (score 0):

You doing it the wrong way. if you want to assign value you can do it like below example

```
val testText = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue()) }
    TextField(
        value = testText.value.copy(
            annotatedString = buildAnnotatedString {
                withStyle(SpanStyle(Color.Blue)) {
                    append(testText.value.text)
                }
            },
        ),
        onValueChange = {
            // should only happen when you type or move cursor
            println("onValueChange called")
            testText.value = it
        },
    )
```

I have tested the code in my Android Studio It is working as in Example 1